# Is there any good XPath Library for Delphi 2007 or above?

Tags: delphi, xpath

I have created my own XPath library for Delphi 2006 and have used it since. It works fine but could have more performance, and I don’t really have the time to maintain it any more.

What other library could I use?

Answer (score 5):

[OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/) has good XML and XPath support, and it's free with source. Works with many versions of Delphi, too, including 2007 and 2009.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call XPath support in OmniXML *good*. It covers only most basic stuff. No support for expressions, for example.

Comment: I guess you'd know that better than I would. :-) It's done everything I needed, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I import the MSXML library and use it directly.  Works like a charm.

Comment: I've used msxml with Delphi for several years now. Works well for me. I've occasionally been caught with the wrong version on a machine, but overall it does the job for me, and I'm sure MS are putting more resources into development than I ever could.

Answer (score 1):

The Open XML, Alternative Document Object Model (**ADOM**) is also a great (and 100% Delphi) XML library including XPath support. It has DTD validation support, but unfortunately no XSD support.

http://www.philo.de/xml/downloads.shtml